# Bound for Lagrange interpolant

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation

I'm having difficulty figuring out how the bound in the below example is determined.

Consider the function $f(x)=e^{-x}$.

For sample points $\{-1,1\}$, the Lagrange basis interpolants are $\ell_0(x)=-\frac{1}{2}(x-1)$ and $\ell_1(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x+1)$, and the polynomial is $p_1(x)=-e^1\frac{(x-1)}{2}+e^{-1}\frac{(x+1)}{2}$. The error on the interval $[-2,2]$ is bounded by $$|f(x)-p_1(x)|\leq\frac{e^2}{2!}(x-1)(x-2)$$

I understand the bound is supposed to be equal to $$\frac{f^{(N+1)}(\xi(x))}{(N+1)!}\prod_{n=0}^N(x-x_n)$$ but I have no idea why $f^{(N+1)}(\xi(x))=e^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the interval for the error estimate is $[-2,2]$. The argument for the estimate is from the full interval, even if the interpolation points $-1,1$ are inside.

---

See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Lagrange_Polynomial_Approximation, note that "here exists $ξ$ in the interval spanned by $x$ and $x_i$, $i=0,…,n$" means the convex hull of all $(n+2)$ points. Apart from that, a nicely written proof.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand why the exponent is 2. Is it that $\xi(x)$ takes whatever value in the interval maximizes the value of $f(x)$?

Comment: Yes, $ ξ(x)$ can be any point in the interval $[-2,2]$. Or more precisely in $[x,1]$ for $x<-1$ or $[-1,1]$ for $x\in[-1,1]$ or $[-1,x]$ for $x>1$. And  since $x\in [-2,2]$ the possibility of $ξ(x)=2-\varepsilon$ with arbitrarily small $\varepsilon$ can not be excluded. Numerically, $ξ(x)\in [-0.5,1]$.

Comment: Okay, so then if we consider the interval $[-3,1]$, the exponent of $e$ on the bound would be 3?

Comment: No, the maximum of $\exp(x)$ for $x\in [-3,1]$ is $\exp(1)$, the function is positive and monotonically increasing.

Comment: The underlying function in the example is $f(x)=e^{-x}$ though, so shouldn't it be -3?

Comment: Yes, you are right in both comments. -- Note that in the error term, everything should be in absolute values.